# Download Landsat imagery from Earth Explorer using Python and metadata

Tags: python, landsat-8

Using metadata (.csv) from Earth Explorer, how can I download it's Landsat imagery. There are a number of options available that use Python, but I am wanting to download using the metadata. I think I remember doing this in the past, but can't find the code. The metadata is from Earth Explorer results page in .csv format and has information on product identifier, scene identifier, date acquired etc.

I remember using this CSV in combination with `wget`, but just not sure if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Once you download the scenes (with entityIds) as a csv from the USGS Earth Explorer, you can edit the same script located [here](https://m2m.cr.usgs.gov/api/docs/example/download_landsat_c2-py) to download the scenes using the Machine-to-Machine API located [here](https://m2m.cr.usgs.gov/). However, it is just as easy to use the api to search for scenes, so no real need to use the csv file.

Comment: could you elaborate with some code (in Python preferably)?